# NETCORE ConfigurationRoot Memory Leak

Tags: asp.net-core, memory-leaks

We are facing memory leak issue with ConfigurationProviders ConfigurationRoot.

[image]

Looks like this issue may have been fixed
https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/861

However, Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration 3.0.0 requires NETCORE 3.0. Can someone please confirm how this fix can be applied with .NETCore 2.2.7? We do not want to upgrade to NETCORE 3 yet, as we have time constraints for project delivery.

Answer (score 2):

This is specifically related to the reload change token, so I would assume disabling reload on the JSON files would negate the issue. That means you'd have to restart your app if you made any changes to the JSON files, but that really shouldn't be much of an issue, as you should really only be making configuration changes as part of a new build and deployment anyways (via your CI/CD pipeline).

Otherwise, no, you'd have to upgrade to Core 3.0, unless this fix gets back-ported into the 2.1 LTS release. That's actually a possibility, so it might be worth calling it out on the issue, since a memory leak is a pretty serious issue to leave unchecked in an LTS release. It might have just flown under the team's radar.

The other possibility is that is *is* back-ported into 2.1, but since you're on 2.2, it's not there. I'm not sure if they'd necessarily back port it into 2.2, since that's not an LTS. As such, your choice may boil down to down-grading to 2.1 or upgrading to 3.0. That's the breaks of the game when you're not not on the LTS release - upgrading may be required.

Comment: What's the best way to get this request. I would assume it impacts every one using less than 3.0.0

Comment: Again, you'd need to test 2.1 to see if that version has the issue. If it does, then you can submit an issue referencing the issue that was fixed in 3.0. Since it's an LTS release, Microsoft has a responsibility to fix it in 2.1. However, they have zero responsibility to fix it in 2.2, since that's not an LTS release. If you go with a non-LTS version, then the responsibility is on you to update to new versions as they arrive.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been sorted, see details here
https://github.com/aspnet/Extensions/issues/2576